# Animate number incrementing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a simple Javascript animation that increments a number until it reaches the target number. The way I'm doing it right now doesn't work however.

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/nLMem/4/

HTML

```
<div id="number">5</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var target = 50;
    var number = $('#number').text();

    while(number <= target) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#number').text(++number);
        }, 30);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is similar to what you want:

```
   var interval = setInterval(function() {
        $('#number').text(number);
        if (number >= target) clearInterval(interval);
        number++;
    }, 30);
```

Your while loop will cause the script execution to 'freeze' while it does its work. It doesn't poll. The other problem is that you call `setTimeout` potentially 50 times. You only need to call `setInterval` once, and clear it once you reach your target number.

Comment: You're missing the `if` around the `clearInterval` line that will only clear the interval if `number` has reached its target. Right now it's only running once.

Comment: Yeah, I knew I was missing something.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't really know the distinction between setTimeout and clearInterval before this!

Comment: Just adding notes here, If incremented by 1, then greater condition is not needed, simple **if(number==target)** is suffice. However if number is incremented by more than 1, then **if(number>=target){number=target;clearInterval(interval);}** would be an ideal solution

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution based on user1508519 code with **increment / decrement automatically and live updating on my page** after ajax search/filter :

```
function animateResultCount(number, target, elem) {
    if(number < target) {
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            $(elem).text(number);
            if (number >= target) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                return;
            }
            number++;
        }, 30);
    }
    if(target < number) {
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            $(elem).text(number);
            if (target >= number) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                return;
            }
            number--;
        }, 30);
    }
}
```

calling my function in ajax success :

```
...
success: function(response) {
    $('div#results').html(response.html);
    animateResultCount($('#rescount').html(),response.newcount,'#rescount');
}
...
```